# Deploying chaincode from tutorial on hyperledger fabric throws error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I've been following the hyperledger fabric tutorials and the asset-transfer-basic chaincode is not being deployed properly. My fabric version is 2.2, and my golang version is 1.18.x .

I've run this command :

```
./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go
```

I'm being presented with this error :

```
Error: failed to read chaincode package at 'basic.tar.gz': open basic.tar.gz: no such 
file or directory
+ PACKAGE_ID=
Error: failed to normalize chaincode path: 'go list' failed with: go: could not 
create module cache: mkdir /home/hypernew/go/pkg/mod: permission denied: exit status 1
```

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case go was not installed. Once I installed go all ok.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to go through the [Getting Started](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/getting_started.html#getting-started) and [Prerequisites](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/prereqs.html#prerequisites).
Have you pulled the code properly from github [fabric-samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples) ? Most of the cases, this should solve the problem.

There is a possibility that the GOPATH env variable is not set properly. As the go module is enabled in the 2.2+ for vendoring, the GOPATH setup is critical.

Try the following command

```
go mod vendor
```

from the chaincode directory. You can even try to compile this package locally and see whether the golang/ gopath etc is correctly handled. Compile using the following

```
go build --tags nopkcs11
```

If this works locally, then the same should work from network.sh also.